# Delete plugin preferences between different sessions of application

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, preferences

I have my own custom plugin which extends org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin class.
Some preferences for this plugin are changed while application working.

But after when I close workbench, they are immediately flushed into hardrive. This is not fully correct for my case: I need some preferences to be stored, while others - not.

My question is: how can i delete some plugin preferences by theirs name from PreferenceStore?

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue that the preferences you want to delete aren't really preferences (as defined and supported by Eclipse).  I'd modify your Activator class to hold those values. It's already a singleton that's accessible everywhere in your plugin and has a lifecycle exactly equal to your application's lifecycle.

Comment: I highly agree. If you don't want to store them, they simply are not preferences and should not be implemented as such. You might want to use Property Dialogs instead.